# android dynamically resize linear layout based on height of scrollview content

Tags: android, dynamic, height, scrollview, android-relativelayout

i have a scroll view, that has a relative layout in it. the content of this scrollview varies, and you may not get the full content at first time.

example, at time 0, onCreate completely executed, current height is 500dip, but at time 5, because some items in the content is fetching results asynchronously, once completed, it will display the result, so at time 5, the height of the content in scroll view can become 600dip

my goal is to have an overlay on top of the content in the scroll view, which should cover the view entirely i.e. height should be the same.

because the height can grow at any size, at different time, i don't think i can set height of the overlay to match_parent

how can i do this in android?

is there a method where i can get notified when the scroll view or relativelayout 's height is growing??  so that whenever it is updated to a larger height, i can change my overlay's height dynamically as well..?

any other method i can consider too

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` inherits from `FrameLayout` and FrameLayout has an `onSizeChanged()` method.  I would extend `ScrollView` and override that method so you can capture size changes.   This might work for you.

Comment: thanks scott, i tried your method, but that method is called once, i am able to get the height argument, but it doesn't seem to be the entire height of the scrollview content because my overlay doesn't covert it fully.

Comment: Hi @user1118019, did you find a solution for that?